# Telegram bot inline keyboard connect to php mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, bots, telegram

```
  <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM league";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $bet_league = json_encode([
        'inline_keyboard'=>[
            [['text'=>"".$row['league_name']."",'callback_data'=>'test']],
        ]
    ]);
        }
    ?>
```

I can't see this code result can you help me ?

Comment: 1) you're overwriting `bet_league` on each loop, and 2) you never echo or return the results.

Comment: please can you explain better ?

Comment: You have to return $bet_league and each step in the while loop overwrites the previous $bet_league.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Test this code :

```php
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM league";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $bet_league_list = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_push($bet_league_list, json_encode([
            'inline_keyboard'=>[
                [['text'=>"".$row['league_name']."",'callback_data'=>'test']],
            ]
        ]));
    }
    
    var_dump($bet_league_list);
?>
```

Comment: Have no result  have other method please ?